# repaint() not working anymore

Tags: java, swing, 2d, rendering

I am currently learning java and am trying to draw on a JFrame via a JPanel...

Problem is, my render code was functioning, but I have changed stuff slighly, now the repaint() method wont refresh the JPanel anymore...

I have System.out.println() calls in every method, but my console just looks like this:

> render
>   render
>   render
>   render

, when I call the render() method. It was working before....
Anyways, here is my code.

```
package Graphics;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Surface extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame;
    RandomFrame rf;

    public Surface(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        rf = new RandomFrame(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
    }

private void draw(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setPaint(Color.blue);

    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();

    g2d.drawImage(rf.getRandom(w, h), null, 0, 0);
    System.out.println("draw");
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("paintComponent");
    super.paintComponents(g);
    draw(g);
}

public void render() {
    System.out.println("render");
    repaint();
}

}
```

, whereas RandomFrame returns a BufferedImage with randomized data.

Comment: If `render` is output `render` to the console, then the problem might be with `RandomFrame` OR the instance of  `Surface` you are updating isn't the one that is on the screen.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Are you possibly calling `render()` in a loop that is run in the event dispatch thread? Painting won't happen until the repaint manager has a chance to do it's job, and looping in the edt would block it. So in that case the drawing would be done only after returning from the code you run in the edt (and in case of an infinite loop, never).

Comment: Try calling repaint() inside an invokeLater(..) call from SwingUtilities

Comment: @Terje `repaint` is one of the few thread safe methods in Swing, it delegates the request to the `RepaintManager` which posts an event onto the EventQueue which is then processed by the EDT...

Comment: Please ignore my comment. It was a corner case where the entire gui was running on another custom thread.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Surface constructor where you take frame, make sure your SurfacePanel is added to the frame. For instance

`public Surface(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        frame.setContentPane(this); // add this line
        rf = new RandomFrame(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
    }`